# Tkinter - How can I add a border in the ScrolledText widgets?

Tags: python, tkinter, border

By default the `Text` and `ScrolledText` widgets don't have a border in the right and in the lower side. How can I add the border where it miss?

Below an example code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, scrolledtext

parent = Tk()
parent.geometry("800x485+370+100")
parent.title("My Software")

WhiteFrame=Frame(parent, background="#ffffff")
WhiteFrame.pack()

TextObj=scrolledtext.ScrolledText(WhiteFrame, wrap=WORD, height=20)
TextObj.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

parent.mainloop()
```

I attached a screenshot too:

[image]

Comment: Actually there is a border there but in light color that may not be seen with a light background.  Try changing border width (`bd` or `border` option) or the border style (`relief` option) to see the different effects on the border.  Suggest setting `bd=2`.

Comment: you are right, I just tried to use this instruction `TextObj=scrolledtext.ScrolledText(WhiteFrame, wrap=WORD, height=20, border=2, relief=SUNKEN)` and now I can see a border, but it's really bad.. I want a border with a  single pixel and with a grey color, as I showed in my screenshot attached. is it possible?

Comment: Did you try without setting the relief option but setting bd=2? Note that border color cannot be changed.

Comment: yeah, I have the same result. `SUNKEN` is the default option for `relief`. with `bd=2` I have an 1px border where it missed, but where it was already present, it is changed in 2px, and I don't like it.

Comment: ok guys, at the end I solved by myself. I encapsulated a Text widget with `bd=0` inside a new frame with a custom border and that's all. if you want you can add the scrolled bar separately using the `ttk.Scrollbar` widget. it has been simple, but a little bit annoying.. from my point of view, these kind of stuffs should be already integreted in Tkinter. Tkinter is simple, but sometimes not enough.

Answer (score -2):

You can add borders to frames with the `highlightborder` and `highlightthickness` parameters when creating the frame.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, scrolledtext

parent = Tk()
parent.geometry("800x485+370+100")
parent.title("My Software")

WhiteFrame=Frame(parent, background="#ffffff", highlightborder = 'black', highlightthickness = 1)
WhiteFrame.pack()

TextObj=scrolledtext.ScrolledText(WhiteFrame, wrap=WORD, height=20)
TextObj.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

parent.mainloop()
```

Comment: `highlightborder` is not a valid option for the Frame widgets. maybe did you mean `highlightbackground`? anyway.. my goal, as I wrote before, is not build a border in my Frame (WhiteFrame) but add it where it miss in the ScrolledText widget (TextObj).

Comment: The "highlight" options aren't for a border, they are for a ring to show whether a widget has the keyboard focus. It might look like a border but it has different properties and different behavior than a border, and normally shouldn't be used in place of a proper border.

Comment: You're right, my bad.  I did mean `highlightbackground` but accidentally wrote border when writing my response.